# CSS: precedence of font-family style

Tags: html, css, fonts

see this snippet

```
<span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';">Storico settimanale</span><BR>
<span style="font-family: 'Helvetica';">Storico settimanale</span><BR>
<span style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;">Storico settimanale</span><BR>
```

I know ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)) that browser MUST try to use the first font, if not found try the second, and go on.

But in FF * versions and IE 11 I got this:

[image]

I supposed to see Helvetica Neue on first and on third line, and Helvetica on the second.

Why I got Helvetica in the third line?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. Anyway, the first line isn't Helvetica Neue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helvetica Neue is a sans-serif font. The image shows a serif font on the first line.  This means that the font you get on the first line is *not* Helvetica Neue. Your browser cannot find Helvetica Neue so it uses the default fallback font for when none of the fonts in the `font-family` list are available.

You get Helvetica on the third line because Helvetica Neue is not available but Helvetica is.

Comment: Actually, in a Windows system (unless Helvetica has been bought and installed), asking for Helvetica in CSS results in Arial being used, since Windows internally performs such a mapping (but does not map the name Helvetica Neue to anything).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get the standard serif font in the first `<span>`, and Helvetica in the last `<span>`, I'd take a punt say that you don't have Helvetica Neue installed on your machine.

Don't forget that the local machine should have the fonts installed, that's why you specify a font-face order.